# I like to implement Flex to Server comet / long polling for games

Tags: apache-flex, flash, comet

I need to try and implement port 80 flex games to server method.

I like to ask if someone already did it before or it is possible to manage flash/flex multi user games with long polling / comet server ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course it is possible. I'd suggest using [URLStream](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLStream.html) (which provides low-level access to downloading data from URL) to receive data on client, since most other methods either do not give you downloaded data continuously (various Loaders) or have problems with proxies (Sockets). Note that [URLStream](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLStream.html) gives you binary data. Use [ProgressEvent.PROGRESS](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLStream.html#event:progress) event to receive data continuously.