# Flex: Long polling (ie, server push) without BlazeDS?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, blazeds, long-polling

Apart from using BlazeDS, are there any pre-existing libraries that implement long polling (or server push) in Flex?

Note: I've read [I like to implement Flex to Server comet / long polling for games](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649712/i-like-to-implement-flex-to-server-comet-long-polling-for-games), but he's only asking if it's possible to implement… Not if implementations exist.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like one possible solution is AmFast, an AMF/remoting implementation in Python: http://code.google.com/p/amfast/

Comment: Faster (2x-12x) AMF encoding/decoding than PyAMF, push notifications, actively maintained and Django examples.  You've just made my day!

Answer (score 1):

[GraniteDS](http://www.graniteds.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=229378) can do this.

A little different, and not really the projects focus, but [Red5](http://www.red5server.org/) can [also do this](http://drawlogic.com/2008/06/26/as3-remoting-and-push-options-for-open-source-red5-and-blazeds/).